# Change "View Cart" and "Checkout" buttons text in Cart Widget Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, widget, woocommerce

I'm trying to find the correct function or filter to edit the text of the buttons "View Cart" and "Checkout" in the Cart Widget of Woocommerce.

My website url : http://modularwave.com/ (just so you know i'm using Brutal, great theme from zigzagpress).

Comment: I've been looking into the Woocommerce documentation and online but only found a way to change the "Proceed to Checkout" button (woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout()) and the "Place Order" button...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **str_ireplace()** to change the text of the button, the following function will allow you to change the text of a Woocommerce button:

```
//The filters.. both are required.
add_filter('gettext', 'change_checkout_btn');
add_filter('ngettext', 'change_checkout_btn');

//function
function change_checkout_btn($checkout_btn){
  $checkout_btn= str_ireplace('Checkout', 'Your New Text', $checkout_btn);
  return $checkout_btn;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works !
Just one thing, how do you change it again ?

If i do :
'Checkout', 'Your New Text', $checkout_btn
or :
'Your New Text', 'Your New Text2', $checkout_btn

It's not working.

Comment: I just tested it now and I see what you mean. You have to still use '**Checkout**', in str_ireplace as that is the text that is generated by Woocommerce for the button when the page loads (even though you might not see it) so you need to go: `str_ireplace('Checkout', 'Your New Text2', $checkout_btn);`

Comment: Yes thanks a lot Daniel it's working like a charm! (It was just the CDN or caching messing with me I guess)

Comment: this must have been depreciated in latest WC as it is not working for us

Comment: I tested this today on WC `2.6.1.4` and it still changed the checkout button text

Answer (score 1):

To easily translate plugins use this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/

It lets you select a plugin.

Note, only plugins with .mo/.po files can be translated.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks a lot for your answer but I'm not there yet (translation I mean).

I'm just looking to change the text in English for that button precisely :).

Comment: Not 100% but that plugin also shows where the string is located. You can then open the file containing the English translated sting and edit it your self. See the plugin as a quick help.